# how to set only vertical for perfect scroll in rtl direction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used [perfect-scroll](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) but this plugin put Y and X scroll bars. How to disable x scroll?

I found this [page](http://www.f1s.me/jscroll/examples/options-useBothWheelAxes.html) but haven't codes ..

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.sidebar').perfectScrollbar({
        useBothWheelAxes: false
    })
});
```

Comment: suppressScrollX - 
When set to true, the scroll bar in X axis will not be available, regardless of the content width. 
Default: false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To suppress the scroll bar in X axis simply set [suppressScrollX](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar#suppressscrollx) to **true** as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.sidebar').perfectScrollbar({
        useBothWheelAxes: false,
        suppressScrollX: true
    })
});
```

Comment: didn't work .. my html direction is rtl and using rtlbootstrap ... is it for this ?

Comment: Probably. You can also try to hide the scrollbar using a CSS definition as follows. `.ps-scrollbar-x-rail { display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue with RTL layout.

I fixed horizontal scrolling of my sidebar by using css `direction: ltr;` to perfect-scrollbar element (`<div class="sidebar">` in my case) and then `direction: rtl;` to inner elements (`<div class="sidebar-body">` in may case).

```
<body class="rtl">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-body">
      .......
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

.

```
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
  .sidebar {
    direction: ltr; // This is the fix
    .sidebar-body {
      direction: rtl; // Then change to rlt back
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this will help you. sorry for my bad English :)